# webpack-import-glob-loader not working with `.scss` files in Rails 6 + Webpacker project

Tags: webpack, glob, webpacker

I'm in the process of migrating at Rails 6 project from `sprockets` to `webpacker`. So far, so good, up until this point.

In the original original `application.scss` of the project, there are statements that import stylesheets that are within subdirectories. The folder structure looks like this:

```
app/assets/stylesheets
- components/
- helpers/
- layout/
- mixins/
- settings/
- variables/
```

Accordingly, the `application.scss` has the following statements:

```scss
@import "variables/*";
@import "mixins/*";
@import "settings/*";
@import "layout/*";
@import "components/*";
@import "helpers/*";
```

I've followed the installation instructions of [`webpack-import-glob-loader`](https://github.com/fred104/webpack-import-glob-loader). Because I'm using `webpacker`, there is no `webpack.config.js`. Instead, it's in `config/webpack/environment.js`. I added the recommended configuration to `environment.js` like this:

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
environment.config = environment.config.merge({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: 'webpack-import-glob-loader'
      },
      {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: 'webpack-import-glob-loader'
      },
    ]
  }
});

module.exports = environment;
```

I also configured `webpacker` to use `app/assets` as the `source_path`, so it should be able to see all the folders within `app/assets`.

To be sure this works, I commented out all the import statements in `application.scss` and added this:

```
@import "stylesheets/variables/colors.scss";
```

This built fine when I ran `./bin/webpack`.

Now when trying out `webpack-import-glob-loader`, I tried this one statement:

```
@import "stylesheets/variables/**/*.scss";
```

This returns the following error when I run `./bin/webpack`:

```
ERROR in ./app/assets/packs/styles/application.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
9 │ @import "stylesheets/variables/**/*.scss";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any suggestions?